# How to Pass object to angularjs control object to antoher angularjs controll in MVC5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5

I have to pass object angularjs controll object to another angularjs controll .

**Control 1**

```
 // This is used for calling post methods from web api with passing prameters
$scope.saveSubs = function () {
    var sub = {
        Des: $scope.des.slice($scope.des.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, $scope.des.lastIndexOf(")")),
        DepartureDate: $scope.departuredate.toString(),
        ReturnDate: $scope.returndate.toString(),
        Rooms: $scope.rooms,
        Adults: $scope.Adults,
        Children: $scope.Children,
        Age: $scope.Age

    };

    var saveSubs = APIService.hotelavailability(sub);
    saveSubs.then(function (d) {
        console.log("Succss");
        if (d.data.hotels.total > 0) {
            $scope.respData = d.data.hotels;
            $scope.respDatapara = d.config.data;
        } else {
            alert("No Data to Display");
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Oops! Something went wrong while saving the data.');
        alert("Oops! Something went wrong while saving the data.");
    });

};
```

Those data i'm populate in Chtml page. i want to that selected object pass to another anguler controll  combind with another MVC controller. now i'm doing pass anguler paramerts to other mvc controller and process again.

**CHTML**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-ng-click="setTab(hotel.code,respDatapara.Des,respDatapara.DepartureDate,respDatapara.ReturnDate,respDatapara.Rooms,respDatapara.Occupancy)">Check Availability</button>
```

Any better way to pass angularjs controller object to another angularjs  controller in mcv5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to communicate with two or more controller is by using Angularjs broadcast. It serves the purpose. 
Below is the link for understanding about angularjs broadcast
http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/angularjs/understanding-emit-broadcast-and-on-in-angularjs